# SD Card File Browser in Android

Tags: android

How to make a file browsing window in Android for accessing, browsing and opening SD card's FAT32 contents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this example: http://www.remwebdevelopment.com/dev/a34/Directory-Browser-Application.html

Answer (score 1):

There's a tutorial here: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/190013-creating-simple-file-chooser/

It isn't like java's JFileChooser but I think it can really help you!