# How to choose a file from SD card

Tags: android, file, explorer, jfilechooser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SD Card File Browser in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107217/sd-card-file-browser-in-android)

Is there any class in android to explore file from SD card or internal phone memory like java's JFileChooser.